# Is it possible to change a xml variable by only its tag name with simplexml in php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I know I can set a variable like that `$xml->path->to->tag = $newValue` . But what if I have only tag name and  don't know its path, I wonder how I can set its variable? is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for

- [`SimpleXml::xpath()` - searches the SimpleXML node for children matching the XPath path.](http://docs.php.net/manual/de/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)

The [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) to search for an element anywhere in the XML document is `//elementName`

Example XML:

```
<foo>
    <bar>
        <baz bam="boom">baddam</baz>
    </bar>
</foo>
```

Example PHP Code:

```
$foo = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$allBazElements = $foo->xpath('//baz');
echo
    $allBazElements[0],        // baddam
    $allBazElements[0]['bam'], // boom
    PHP_EOL;

$allBazElements[0][0] = 'changed';
$allBazElements[0]['bam'] = 'changed too';

echo $foo->asXml();
```

will output ([demo](http://codepad.org/SH15UNmG))

```
baddamboom
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo>
    <bar>
        <baz bam="changed too">changed</baz>
    </bar>
</foo>
```